# Background Image not appearing in Outlook Emails

Tags: html, email, outlook

A Background image that I have been using for a while, used to appear in outlook 2013 emails and all of the sudden it isn't showing up anymore but, does show up for other platforms, like gmail. I have tried everything, including renaming and resizing and it is still having this same issue but only in outlook2013. I also played around with the code a little and it seems I can't get any images to appear but, I can change the background color.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" style="margin:0 auto;" background="/email/2016/background.jpg">
<tr>
<td>

<table width="40%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="deviceWidth">
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="font-size: 11px; color: #f1f1f1; font-weight: normal; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; line-height: 26px; vertical-align: top; text-align:left" class="center">

<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="/2015/facebook1.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" border="0" /></a>

<a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="/email/2015/twitter1.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" border="0" /></a>

<a href="http://www.pinterest.com"><img src="/email/2015/pinterest1.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Vimeo" title="Pinterest" border="0" /></a>

<a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="/email/2015/youtube.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Facebook" title="Youtube" border="0" /></a>

<a href="http://instagram.com"><img src="/email/2015/instagram.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Facebook" title="Instagram" border="0" /></a>
<br />

 <a href=""><img src="/email/2014/img/logo.png" alt="" border="0" style="padding-top: 5px;" /></a><br>
 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #848484; font-weight: normal;">stuff</a><br>
 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #848484; font-weight: normal;">stuff</a><br/>
 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #848484; font-weight: normal;">© stuff</a>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="45%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" class="deviceWidth">
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="font-size: 11px; color: #f1f1f1; color:#999; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding-bottom:20px" class="center"> 
 <br>If you no longer wish to receive emails 
 <a href="/unsubscribe.jsp" style="color:#999;text-decoration:underline;">unsubscribe</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- End 4 Columns -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use full link for you Image with

> http://example.com

Comment: i edited it like that just for privacy purposes. the actual code has the full link.